# Converting a SQL contains query for Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I am currently converting some SQL to C# code against Entity Framework and have come up against an issue with a keyword search query.

The (very) simplified query ultimately looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM SomeTable
WHERE CONTAINS(Col1, Col2, Col3, '"word"')
```

As per the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/contains-transact-sql this method searches for fuzzy or precise matches on words or phrases. So if I ran a search for the keyword of "word" I will get results where Col1, Col2 or Col3 have the instance of "word".

I have tried writing a string contains method against Entity Framework:

```
Context.Where(i => i.Col1.Contains("word") || i.Col2.Contains("word") || i.Col3.Contains("word"))
```

However this produces a wildcard like query '%word%' and returns results that are not relevant, for example I get matches on "word" and "swords".

How would I be able to get the same results as the SQL contains query?

Comment: So all cols need to return specifically word and nothing else?

Comment: is there any equals() method available?

Comment: So `keyword` returns `word` and `swords`? you might have to use regex instead of `Contains`

Comment: Apologies the example might not be clear with the wording I have used. I will update the keywords to be a bit more clear.

Comment: There is no way, but you can use some (ugly) workarounds, for example: http://www.entityframework.info/Home/FullTextSearch.

Comment: Thanks this is great, not ideal but answers the question. You should post as an answer.

Comment: Are you using code-first or database-first for your EF model?

Comment: It is a Code first project

Answer (score 0):

You have to write a custom SQL function and call this one from C#.

For example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Search](@Search nvarchar(4000))
RETURNS TABLE
AS
RETURN (
    SELECT 
        *
    FROM 
        [dbo].[SomeTable]
    WHERE 
        CONTAINS(Col1, Col2, Col3, @Search)
)
GO
```

When it is generated to EDMX use it like this

```
var query = this.DataContext.Search("my search string");
```

Comment: I guess he is looking for C# code - EF, not SQL query

Comment: So you are suggesting there is no sql contains equivalent for entity framework?

Comment: no native one - you only have to make SQL function and call from EF or use raw query using SqlQuery or you can also make some own expression visitor which changes like with contains.

Comment: Thanks, I will keep this in mind. I am trying to get away from having custom sql queries as much as possible but at least I have this option if there is no other way.

Answer (score 0):

Try Using SqlMethods.Like

Example:

```
Context.Where(x=> SqlMethods.Like(x.Col1,'word') 
||SqlMethods.Like(x.Col2,'word')).ToList();
```

You can find SqlMethods Under System.Data.Linq.SqlClient;